# Where to add JVM parameter nojce in weblogic?

Tags: weblogic, jvm-arguments

I need to add -Dweblogic.security.SSL.nojce=true flag in to startWeblogic.sh file as JVM parameter.

Is there any specific place I should add it in script file  and is startWeblogic.sh correct file to add the flag ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience we have always added JVM parameters to the
    ${WL_HOME}/bin/setDomainEnv.sh
script as an extra property under the
    $EXTRA_JAVA_PROPERTIES
variable.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Garreth. I will try it and let here know.

Answer (score 3):

`setDomainEnv.sh` is called by `startWebLogic.sh` so either location works. Keep in mind this will apply to all servers. If you want it on a server by server basis, you can add that -D option in the admin console:

```
 Environment -> Servers -> Your Server -> Configuration (tab) -> Server Start (sub-tab)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It is just one server so I guess I will do it in script file.